# Is it safe to use the first 22 characters of a NFT pubkey as a primary key for a DB

Tags: uuid, private-key, solana, nft

I am wondering if is safe to only use the first 22 characters instead of the 44 characters of a pubkey of an NFT as a primary key of a MySQL DB. I have a DB with huge data and could save a lot of space thanks to this approach. For instance having the following pubkey:

`AQoKYV7tYpTrFZN6P5oUufbQKAUr9mNYGe1TTJC9wajM`

Would it be safer to use the first 22 characters:

`AQoKYV7tYpTrFZN6P5oUuf`

Would it be safer using the first 11chars plus the trailing 11chars, or doesn't make any difference?

`AQoKYV7tYpTe1TTJC9wajM`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming.

Comment: I disagree, many people working with the Solana Blokchain may find this question useful, I would also like to know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A public key is 32 bytes, so those "44 characters" are actually the base-58 representation of those 32 bytes.

If you're only storing 22 characters, let's simplify things and say that you're storing 16 bytes out of 32 total.  The chance of two pubkeys sharing the same 16-byte sequence is `1 / 256^16 = 1 / 2^128 = 2.9 * 10 ^ -39`, which is very unlikely, but possible.

Here's another way to approach the problem -- how about storing the full pubkey as 32 bytes instead of as a string?  Then you won't ever lose any precision.